# Closing ApplicationContext

Tags: spring

I am using Spring 4.3. I am using `ConfigurableApplicationContext` and calling `close()` on it. As expected method annotated with `@PreDestroy` is called.

But I have seen that even if I don't call close then also `@PreDestroy` methods are called. I was under the impression that there is a chance of memory leak if `close()` is not called. Am I wrong?

Also, if I am using web application ,  what is the correct way to close the applicationcontext, regsiterShutdownHook?

Comment: If you are using a web application and use the normal way to create a context (i.e. use a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`) you don't need to do anything/worry all is taken care of.

Comment: thanks, I understand your point in case of webapplication. The first part of my query is related to simple application and second is related to webapplication. For simple application , please share your views

Comment: The easiest is to simply register the shutdown hook, or if you really control the construction of the context do both... Or use Spring Boot which takes care of that for you regardless the type of application.

Comment: okay, I got it so either I should use close() or  registerShutdownHook()..anyone of these will do..if not done , there will be memory leak  I think..only thing I could not understand is that how come my predestroy gets called when I don't explicitly call close() or registerShutdownHook();, u r saying spring boot does it automatically - I am using SpringApplication.run to get ApplicationContext but not using @EnableAutoConfiguration..could this be the reason

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint inside a ```PreDestroy``` method, and look at the callstack to see where which code is calling ```ApplicationContext.close()```. If you are using Spring in a WebApp I'm assuming that you are using ```AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer``` (or spring boot) and then the context is automatically closed.

Comment: I used spring with Junit and SpringApplication.run , without EnableAutoConfiguration - I read somewhere that even if not using boot for autoconfig then also instead of specifying specific ApplicationContext , use SpringApplication.run to get the context.i did check more on PreDestroy.so it is closed by boot it seems .. INFO 3352 --- [main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext4241e0f4: startup date [...] root of context hierarchy Test PreDestroy Called

Comment: I have checked the code of SpringApplication , In SpringApplication

In run() method -> it has a method : refreshContext(context); -> And in refreshContext() , we have context.registerShutdownHook();  

So when we are calling SpringApplication.run()  , it is closing this context on JVM shutdown and my predestroy method is called

And following is the documentation reference for the same :

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-exit

Answer (score 1):

Either you can register shutdown hook :

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
context.registerShutdownHook();
```

or add a listener to do something :

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);

    context.addApplicationListener(new ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
            // some logic
        }
    });
```